# How to solve DOM hierarchy,Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$x'

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

I am studying DOM structure, trying to see how to select HTML elements

This is my source image
[image]

These are my efforts at console

[image]

What is uncaught DOM expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An uncaught DOM exception means your XPath selector was invalid and you didn't "catch" it with error handling or something like a [try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

The specific problems with your selectors are, in order:

- a trailing slash
- spaces used as delimiters rather than slashes
- both of the above